# CodeIgniter session variable not setting

Tags: php, codeigniter, jquery-mobile

I'm having a crazy odd issue with sessions on my site right now.  First off, on the regular version of my site it works great.  When I switch to the jQuery Mobile version it doesn't carry the session variable to the next page.

```
//var_dump($this->account->getHash()); //returns 4l1jk14n45na;kj45899cv8
$this->session->set_userdata('accHash', $this->account->getHash());

header('Location: /myaccount/');
```

The problem is, the variable doesn't exist on the next page.

```
var_dump($this->session->userdata('accHash')); //returns null
```

The only thing different in the mobile/standard version of my site is the set of templates, css, and js that it uses.  The controllers are the same.

Any ideas on what I can look at see what's wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

It is probably from your web server. Have a look whether the session path was set correctly.

Comment: This works on the site when I'm not using jQuery Mobile, so I know the session path is correct.  Any other thoughts?